# How can I handle large console output in Windows 7?

Tags: java, python, winapi, windows-7, console

I am working with a Java based application. When it starts, it opens a console and writes its output there.

However, the output sometimes is that large that it doesn't fit the consolee window (the console window has a maximum of 10000 lines), the output is more than 10 times larger).

I have already tried downloading other console applications (like con Emu), but there the maximum amount of lines (about 32760) is too small too.

I have Ultra Edit on my PC, which can capture DOS command output, but as I am debugging my program, I can't start the debugging session out of a simple text editor dialog box.

Now I'm left with several solutions:

- redirect the output of the console window of an already running process to a local file on my system.
- yet find another console emulation tool which is not limited by a pre-defined value.
- develop sych a console emulation tool myself (preferably in Python, Java or Visual Basic), but in order to do this, I need to know from Windows 7 API how to start doing that.

Can somebody put me on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: I'd just send everything to a file. What wrong with that ?

Comment: Can you edit the java application ?

Comment: IMO, if your ouput is more than 1000 lines stdout is not the way to go... I would store it in a file, and if stdout is required you could split it in blocks of 10000 lines (Like `more` or `less` in linux)

Comment: Does the application always allocate a new console, or will it reuse the console when started from the command prompt? If the latter is the case, simply redirect output to a file by using the `>` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a Java application as you say, you might be able to wrap the startup in a class of your own, replacing `System.out` and `System.err` with something based on [`TeeOutputStream`s](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) that will print both to the console (which you saved from before value of System.out) and to a log-file you set up.

Like this:

```
public class LogWrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        PrintStream err = System.err;

        System.setOut(new TeePrintStream(out, new PrintStream("system.out.log")));
        System.setErr(new TeePrintStream(err, new PrintStream("system.err.log")));

        the.original.ClassYouWereCalling.main(args);
    }
}
```

*Note: The `TeePrintStream` you'd have to do still...*